# Buttons: Change value by ID in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I‘m trying to have a set of buttons in an `{{#each}}<button>...</button>{{/each}}` block, and to get the target values by an ID of the model ...

Let’s say there is a controller with model and action:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    Texts: [
        {id: "1", name: "One", sample: "Hello!"},
        {id: "2", name: "Two", sample: "Hello! Hello!"},
        {id: "3", name: "Three", sample: "Hello! Hello! Hello! "},
    ],

    theText: "Test",

    actions: {
        setText: function(id) {
            var theText= this.get('Texts.sample', id);
            this.set('theText');
            console.log(theText);
        }

});
```

and this in the template:

```
{{#each Texts as |Text|}}
    <button {{action "setText" Text.id}}>{{Text.name}}</button>
{{/each}}

<span>{{theText}}</span>
```

... this is my idea, but all I get is an *undefined* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define array properties in init method.
2. Use [findBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_findBy) method to get matching id row.

```
    export default Ember.Component.extend({
        Texts: undefined,
        theText: "Test",
        init() {
            this._super(...arguments);
            this.set('Texts', [
                { id: "1", name: "One", sample: "Hello!" },
                { id: "2", name: "Two", sample: "Hello! Hello!" },
                { id: "3", name: "Three", sample: "Hello! Hello! Hello! " },
            ]);
        },
        actions: {
            setText: function(id) {
                let result = this.get('Texts').findBy('id', id);
                this.set('theText', result.sample);
                console.log(result);
            }
        }
    });
```